# copy data to a specific bit location

Tags: c++, c

i need to copy 4 pieces of data into a byte array, but the data needs to copied to specific bit locations.

here's an example.

my 4 pieces of data are below.  they go in order from left to right as detailed in the binary and are separated by hyphens for visibility:

- 1341 = 0x05D3 (always truncated to 14 bits)
- 0001 = 0x0001 (always truncated to 14 bits)
- 987654 = 0x0F1206 (always truncated to 20 bits)
- 20110411 = 0x0132DC4B (always truncated to 25 bits)

completed necessary output:

0C 53 D0 00 7C 48 1A 65 B8 97

and in binary, the first and last bits are parity:

1-00010100111101-00000000000001-11110001001000000110-1001100101101110001001011-1

i'm at a loss on how to do this.  is possible to use bit shifting somehow?

Comment: How do you have the data stored currently?

Comment: the data started from its source as BCD chars arrays like: 0x01030401.  i now have them in WORDs, an int and a DWORD, but can certainly move the data to byte arrays that represent the values if it would make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could allocate a array that is large enough to hold all the data:

```
unsigned char buffer[10];
```

and then fill in the data with bitwise shifting operators `<<` and `>>`. To combine bit numbers from multiple source variables into one destination variable use the bitwise-or operator `|`.
For example:

```
unsigned short block1 = 0x05d3; // binary: 00000101 00111101
// first byte: 1 - 000101 0
buffer[0] = 1 << 7 | (block1 << 2) >> 9;
```

Comment: not sure this works.  if i'm understanding this correctly, applying a 2 byte short to a byte truncates 1/2 the data, right?

Comment: This example just sets the first byte of the destination. So the parity bit in the first bit, then the first 7 bits of the 14 bit long block1. The rest of block1 should go in the second byte

Comment: understood.  so splitting up each block's data in multiple bytes is done in separate operations.  i'll give this is a shot.

Comment: this worked.  bunch of bit shifting did it.  thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you use `std::bitset` to represent your numbers. While the following does ***NOT*** solve your problem, I wonder wheter it can help you get to where you want?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<bitset>

struct Data {
  std::bitset<14> d1;
  std::bitset<14> d2;
  std::bitset<20> d3;
  std::bitset<25> d4;
  Data(unsigned int d1, unsigned int d2, unsigned int d3, unsigned int d4)
      : d1(d1),
        d2(d2),
        d3(d3),
        d4(d4) {}  
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Data& data) {
  os<<data.d1<<"-"
    <<data.d2<<"-"
    <<data.d3<<"-"
    <<data.d4;
  return os;      
}

int main() {
  Data d(1341, 1, 987654, 20110411);
  std::cout<<d<<std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
00010100111101-00000000000001-11110001001000000110-1001100101101110001001011
```

Comment: how would i apply this to a byte array for output?